# Bad memory access when dereferencing results of std::find_if

Tags: c++, debugging

```
bool hasId(string id, vector<User>& map)
{
    User ans = *(find_if(map.begin(), map.end(), [&](User d)
    {   return (id==(d).uid());}));
    return ans.uid() == id;
}
```

Comment: Could `ans` be null when you're referencing it?

Comment: It can return the end iterator, which should not be dereferenced.

Comment: What if there is no element of the vector that matches?

Comment: @PaulTomblin Nothing special, then it returns the same iterator (which is off-by-one, by definition, because we have semi-closed intervals here.)

Comment: I really have no idea how this can legitimately be considered "too localized"... I think you guys are a bit close-happy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If no matches are found then `find_if` returns `last()`, in your case, `map.end()`.  `end()` does not return a valid iterator (it's one past the last element), yet you assume that a match is always found and proceed to dereference the return value unconditionally.  This is a problem.

You need to perform a check before the dereference.  Without the check your function simply assumes that a match is always found as `ans.uid() == id` is the predicate to `find_if` (and thus redundant), so you may as well just replace the entire thing with `return true;` as it stands :)

```
bool hasId(string id, vector<User>& map)
{
    return map.end() != find_if(map.begin(), map.end(), [&](User d)
    {   
        return id == d.uid();
    });   
}
```

On a side note, it's kinda weird to call a `vector` a `map`, confusing at least.

---

[Documentation for find_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)

Relevant bit:

```
template< class InputIt, class UnaryPredicate >
InputIt find_if( InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryPredicate p );
```

> **Return value**
>
> Iterator to the first element satisfying the condition **or last if no such element is found.**

Answer (score 4):

Your implementation could be simply this:

```
bool hasId(string id, vector<User>& map)
{
    return map.end() !=
           find_if(map.begin(), map.end(), [&](User d){ return d.uid()==id; });
}
```

But since you're using C++11 anyway, then you can just use [any_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of).

```
return any_of(map.begin(), map.end(), [&](User d){ return d.uid()==id; });
```

Comment: +1 for the `any_of` suggestion